# Paging with Database + Network

Tags: android, pagination, android-jetpack

i have to implement pagination on room db with network API. as google recommended the database serves as the single source of truth.
so i want to implement paging on db. 
first of all data show from db when user scroll then API call and data store on room db and live data observe that data and update ui.

i'm search many of project but i don't find any result.
but at last i got google pagination project but that was in kotlin. i don't know kotlin language.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingSample

can anyone suggest me pagination room db with network API in java language. please help me

Comment: you dont have to know kotlin: simply follow what classes it uses and how

Answer (score 0):

I have an implementation for it in my [GitHub](https://github.com/ForceTower/PlayTime/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/forcetower/playtime/ds/DataSource.java), you can use it as a sample and apply it to your specific case.

Kotlin is nice, you should try it out some time :)